# "scope not allowed" on localhost only

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm getting started with Google App Engine with Java, and using Google Cloud Endpoints with OAuth 2.0.  I have one simple endpoint working correctly, but only when deployed.  When I run it on my local machine I get this error:

```
Mar 10, 2014 4:38:54 PM com.google.api.server.spi.WebApisUserService getCurrentUser
INFO: getCurrentUser: AccessToken; scope not allowed
```

Here is my endpoint code:

```
@Api(
    name = "sd",
    version = "v1",
    scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE },
    clientIds = { Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID })
public class Feeds {

    public Feed sample(User user) {

        if (user == null) {
            return new Feed("Public Feed.");
        } else {
            return new Feed("Feed for " + user.getEmail());
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "<snip>.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    public static final String EMAIL_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    public static final String API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID = com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID;
}
```

As I said, when I deploy this and access it via the API Explorer in all works perfectly.  When I have the OAuth toggle on, it returns `Feed for <my email address>`, and when I turn it off it returns `Public Feed.`

However, when run against my local machine it always returns `Public Feed.`  When the OAuth toggle is on, it prints the error pasted at the top of this post to the server's console.  I am accessing the two api explorers with the urls `https://<app_id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer` and `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Though I haven't tested this since 1.8.7, this just started happening with me after updating to 1.9.0 as well, so I think it's a bug. Probably [worth filing with them](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3).